# Bounded sequence with divergent Cesaro means

Tags: real-analysis, game-theory, cesaro-summable

Is there a bounded real-valued sequence with divergent Cesaro means (i.e. *not* Cesaro summable)?

More specifically, is there a bounded sequence $\{w_k\}\in l^\infty$ such that $$\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^M w_k}{M}$$ does *not* exist?

I encountered this problem while studying the *limit of average payoffs* criterion for ranking payoff sequences in infinitely repeated games.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider $1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,\cdots$ (one $1$, two $-1$, four $1$, eight $-1$, ...) Then
$$\frac{1-2+2^2-2^3+\cdots+(-2)^n}{1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^n}=\frac{1-(-2)^{n+1}}{3(2^{n+1}-1)}$$
This sequence is divergent. So $(\sum_{k\le M}a_k)/M$ has divergent subsequence, and it implies nonexistence of Cesaro mean of $a_n$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $(a_n)$ be any increasing sequence of positive integers such that
$$
a_{n+1}\ge 2(a_1+\cdots+a_{n})
$$
for all $n$. Now let $(x_n)$ be the sequence 
$$
\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{a_1 \text{ times }},\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{a_2 \text{ times }},\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{a_3 \text{ times }},\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{a_4 \text{ times }},\ldots
$$
It easily follows that
$$
\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n}}}{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n}}\ge \frac{a_{2n}}{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n}}=1-\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n-1}}{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n}}\ge 1-\frac{1}{1+2}=\frac{2}{3}
$$
for all $n$ and, on the other hand,
$$
\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n-1}}}{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n-1}}\le \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n-1}}{a_1+\cdots+a_{2n}} \le \frac{1}{1+2}=\frac{1}{3},
$$
hence it cannot converge.

Comment: Interesting example. Could you tell where you got the motivation for this, or where have you seen something similar maybe?