# Continuous Linear Functional on $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I'd like help answering two questions.

1) Prove that there is a continuous linear functional on $\ell^\infty$ such that $f(e_n)=0 \ \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $f(a)=5$ where $a=(1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots)$.

2) Prove that there is not a continuous linear functional on $\ell^\infty$ such that $f(e_n)=0 \ \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $f(a)=4$ for $a=(1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\ldots)$.

Note: $e_n$ stand for the point $(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0,0)$ with $1$ in the $n$-th position and the rest $0$'s, i.e $(e_n)=(\delta_{mn})$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldn't solve it. I didn't even thought of using HB theorem. But I think that's the way now that you mention it.

Answer (score 4):

The key observation (for both questions) is that the Banach subspace of $\ell^\infty$ generated by $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots\}$ is $c_0$.

Comment: Could you go deeper on the question?

Comment: I believe I managed to solve the question (2). But didn't you mean that if S=span{$e_1,e_2,...$} then the closure of S is $c_0$?

Comment: @Raul The "Banach subspace" generated by a set of vectors is indeed the closure of their span.

Answer (score 2):

There are positive continuous functionals on $\ell_\infty$, which map every convergent sequence to its limit. [Banach limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) are one class of such functionals, see fore example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80564/show-that-liminf-n-to-inftyx-n-le-alphax-le-limsup-n-to-inftyx-n-f). Another example is a limit of a bounded sequence along an ultrafilter, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit), [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35450/applications-of-ultrafilters/35461#35461) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51476/basic-facts-about-ultrafilters-and-convergence-of-a-sequence-along-an-ultrafilte).

For the second part just notice that if $f(e_n)=0$, then also each $x_n=(1,1/2,1/3,\dots,1/n,0,0,\dots,0,\dots)$ is mapped to zero. Since $f(x_n)=0$ and $a_n\to a$ in $\ell_\infty$, we get $f(a)=0$.

Comment: Martin, while that is true, nothing that sophisticated is needed for question 1. You just use that $c_0$ is a proper closed subspace and apply Hahn-Banach.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1), you could provide an explicit example of such a functional.  One such example would be $f:\ell^\infty\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(\{x_n\}) = 5 \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k
$$
For the purposes of your question, it suffices to prove that $f$ is a bounded (i.e. continuous) linear functional satisfying the necessary criteria where it is defined.  From there, one must use the HB theorem to extend $f$ to give a functional over $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: The function you suggested is not defined for all bounded sequences; the limit $\lim \frac1n \sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k$ does not always exist. Some such examples are given in answers to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444889/bounded-sequence-with-divergent-cesaro-means However, your function can be extended to a linear continuous functional on $\ell_\infty$. (For example using Hahn-Banach, or using ultrafilters; whichever you prefer.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak duly noted.

Comment: I think it would work if I define for $x=(x_1,x_1,...)$, $f(x)=5 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ on $c$, the space of convergent sequences in $\Bbb{R^\infty}$. So $f(e_n)=0 \ \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $f(a)=5$, then find use a sublinear function such as $p(x)=5 \cdot ||x||_{l^\infty}$ that fits the conditions for Hanh-Banch and extend it to $l^\infty$.

Comment: @Raul that works too. I suppose it is a better choice than mine.