# Prove that $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i/n) \sim \exp (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i/n)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots$ be an infinite sequence of real numbers. Assume that they are bounded, $|x_i| \le C < \infty$ for all $i$ for some $C$.

Is it true that, for any such sequence

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{i = 1}^n \left( 1 + \frac{x_i}{n} \right)
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \exp \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i
\right)?\qquad\qquad (1)$$

So far I only have the heuristic argument

$$\prod_{i = 1}^n \left[ \left( 1 + \frac{x_i}{n} \right)^n \right]^{1 / n}
\rightarrow \prod_{i = 1}^n \mathrm e^{x_i / n} = \exp \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i= 1}^n x_i \right)$$

but I can't be sure that it is correct.

**Update:** The answer to my original question, that the lims in (1) are equal, is NO. In fact the limits might not exist. However their ratio goes to 1, so the two expressions are asymptotically equivalent. I've updated the title to reflect the actual true statement that was proved in the answers here to make this easier to find.

Comment: You argument clearly holds for constant sequences, interesting idea

Comment: Take $n$ to be greater than $C$, so that $|x_i| < n$ for all $i$. Then $1 + \frac{x_i}{n}$ is strictly between $0$ and $2$, so its logarithm is well defined. The natural logarithm is a continuous function, so you can instead look at the $\log$ of both the sides of your equation and see if they are equal.

Comment: The title of your question differs from the text.

Comment: @PaulFrost Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: In general $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$ does not exist. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/444889.

Comment: @PaulFrost I strengthened the conditions. But not sure if it will help ...

Comment: In general $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{x_i}{n}\right)}{\exp(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)} = 1$ but the statement $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{x_i}{n}\right) = \exp(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)$ need not make sense. This is because the limit need not exists! As an example, consider $x_i = (-1)^m C$ where $m = \lfloor \log_2 i\rfloor$, you will find $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ oscillate around $\pm \frac{C}{3}$  and doesn't converge.

Comment: @achillehui Ah great. Your statement does not need the $x_i$ to be less than one I suppose, it only needs them to be bounded. Can you prove it? Thanks!

Comment: The strengthened condtions do not help.If you have convergence for $C < 1$, then also for **any** $C$ (consider $x'_i = x_i/2C$).

Comment: @PaulFrost True. I think the solution is achillehui's statement.

Comment: @achillehui: you are right that if the limit is undefined we cannot strictly write the identity. But I suppose that it should be read in the understanding that if they exist then they are equal, if not defined then they are both so. Is that "viable" ?

Comment: @GCab That the limits are equal if they exist is a consequence of the more general statement that their ratio tends to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I). $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ need not exist, even if $(x_j)_j$ is a bounded sequence.

(2). Let $A_n=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+x_j/n) .$ Let $B_n=\exp (n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j).$ Let  $n>C.$

We have $\forall j\leq n\,( |x_j|<n)$ so $$\log A_n=\sum_{j=1}^n\log (1+x_j/n)=$$ $$=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{s=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{s-1}(x_j/n)^s/s=$$ $$=(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j/n) + R_n$$ $$\text { where } \quad  |R_n|=|\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{s-1}(x_j/n)^s/s|\leq$$ $$\leq  \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(C/n)^s/s=n\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(C/n)^s/s=$$ $$=(C^2/n)\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} (C/n)^t/(t+2)\leq$$ $$\leq (C^2/n)\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}(C/n)^t=(C^2/n)\cdot 1/(1-C/n).$$ So $\lim_{n\to \infty}R_n=0.$

But we also have $R_n=\log A_n-\log B_n=\log(A_n/B_n).$ So $\lim_{n\to \infty}\log (A_n/B_n)=0.$ So $\lim_{n\to \infty}(A_n/B_n)=1.$

So if the Cesaro mean $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ exists then the LHS and RHS in your Q are equal. If the Cesaro mean does not exist, then the ratio of the LHS to the RHS still converges to $1.$

Comment: My first thought was that it was wrong and I tried to find a simple counter-example.

Comment: I'm beginning to see that by showing it through the logarithm, precise results follow more readilly. For instance, if Σ{j=1 to n}x_j^m = o(n^m)∀m, which I think _unbounded_ sets could be devised to satisfy, then the theorem will hold for that set.

Comment: ∀m >1, that is. If Σ{j=1 to n}x_j=o(n), then that perhaps raises _another_ question asto the validity of the theorem. It might be an interesting matter, actually, _precisely_ what sets, bounded or _un_ -bounded, it's valid _for_.

Comment: I think the set _absolutely does_ have to be bounded, doesn't it. Otherwise the arithmetic mean ceases to exist as n →∞.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey .  An unbounded sequence can have a Cesaro mean. But in my A  I assumed a bounded sequence, as in the Q.

Comment: TBPH, I don't know what you mean by a '_Cesaro_ mean.' Is it possible for² unbounded values to occur in a sequence, and yet the sequence still have an arithmetic mean by reason of their occurences being spread-out ever more thinly? Maybe if you could do that you _could conceivably_ have an unbounded sequence & this theorem still hold ... ie unboundedness be _sufficient_ but not _necessary_.

Comment: I was 'brewing this thought earlier today : if you have a bounded sequence, and you add to it a sequence that's unbounded ... _but_ the gaps between terms in the bounded sequence that you add these unbonded ones to _increases faster_ than the size of the unbounded terms, then the sequence _will still have a mean_. I can see how questions like this could get very _delicate_.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey . If $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^na_j$ exists then $L$ is called the Cesaro (or Cesaro-Stoltz) mean. Suppose $a_{2^i}=i$ when $i\in \Bbb N$ and $a_j=0$ when $ j$ is not an integer-power of $2.$

Comment: So the _Cesaro-Stolz_ mean (the second -mentioned in a paper always loses the having their name on the theorem!) is just precisely what we've been talking-about all along - the limit of the arithmetic mean in the limit of proceeding along the sequence. So yes I _do see_ then how an unbounded sequence _can have_ a Cesaro-Stolz mean. Thanks for that piece of instruction.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey . The "traditional" names for terms or results are sometimes inaccurate, and at times confusing. The set-theoretic Cantor-Bernstein theorem in one book is the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem of another, and the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem of yet another.

Comment: I'm sure the debates get positively _internecine_! ¶ Whilst I'm here, an angle I've been meditating upon is this - you have a bounded series, and from every element you 'pinch' a bit; and then after f(n) elements you put all these little bits back on to an element. If f(n) is increasing, such that the gap between elements you 'unload' all the little bits that you've pinched back onto _increases_ all the time, then you'll have a sequence that increases without limit, but with mean the same as that of the bounded sequence you started with - you're just moving 'number-stuff' around _internally_.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey . That will work. Analogously, if $f:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R^+$ is continuous, the existence of $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)d$t does not imply that $ f$ is bounded.

Comment: Also analogously though, the _unboundednesses_ would have to be _pulses_ of decreasing fequency - the gaps between then decreasing at the same order as some measure of the _heft_ of them - the integral of them between some limits that _comprise_ the unboundedness.

Answer (score 2):

Given
$$
S(n) = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {1 + {{x_{\,i} } \over n}} \right)} \quad \left| {\;\left| {x_{\,i} } \right| \le C \le \left\lceil C \right\rceil  = D} \right.
$$
let's take $D<<n$ so that we can put $n=mD\quad | \; 2 \le m \in \mathbb Z$.
Thereafter taking the logarithm we get 
$$
\eqalign{
  & \ln S(n) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\ln \left( {1 + {{x_{\,i} } \over n}} \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{mD} {\ln \left( {1 + {{x_{\,i} } \over {mD}}} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{mD} {\ln \left( {1 + {{\left( {x_{\,i} /D} \right)} \over m}} \right)}  \cr} 
$$

The Lagrange formulation of the Taylor remainder gives
$$
\ln \left( {1 + z} \right)\quad \left| {\,\left| z \right|} \right. < 1/2
 = z - {1 \over {2\left( {1 + \zeta } \right)^{\,2} }}z^{\,2} \quad \left| {\, - 1/2 < \zeta } \right. < 1/2
$$
so that
$$
\left| {\, - {1 \over {2\left( {1 + \zeta } \right)^{\,2} }}\;} \right|z^{\,2}  < 2z^{\,2} 
$$

Therefore we can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & \ln S(n) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{mD} {\ln \left( {1 + {{\left( {x_{\,i} /D} \right)} \over m}} \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{mD} {\left( {{{\left( {x_{\,i} /D} \right)} \over m} + O\left( {{1 \over {m^{\,2} }}} \right)} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{mD} {{{\left( {x_{\,i} /D} \right)} \over m} + O\left( {{1 \over m}} \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{x_{\,i} } \over n} + O\left( {{1 \over {n/D}}} \right)}  \cr} 
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\, \to \;\infty } \ln S(n)
 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\, \to \;\infty } \left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{x_{\,i} } \over n} + O\left( {{1 \over {n/D}}} \right)} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\, \to \;\infty } \left( {{1 \over n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {x_{\,i} } } \right) \cr} 
$$

Thus, whether the two limits exist or not, their ratio is in any case $1$.

Comment: Did you see @achillehui's comment?

Comment: The sequences are not necesserily convergent. See the above comments.

Comment: @becko: I added a comment above about the way to understand your "identity": is that correct ?

Comment: If the limits exist I think your derivation is valid

Comment: Your A appeared as I was typing mine. I am an extremely slow typist and also I always have many errors to correct.

Comment: @PaulFrost: understanding the "equality" as per my comment above (if exist they are equal, else both do not exist) would it then be "viable"?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: well, sorry for the .. overspeed :). In any case I wellcome any edit/integration from your side, we can output a common answer !

Comment: We consider only $n>C$ so we can take the logs of the individual terms....+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: well, yes, I gave that for understood that $1<m$: but it is better to eplicitate that, thanks

Comment: The idea of your answer is certainly correct. You use the power series $\ln(1+x) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - \dots$. But is not completely clear to me what $m$ should be. Perhaps you assume that $C$ is an integer (which is of course allowed) and only consider $n = mC$? Moreover, you should argue why $O(1/m^2)$ is based on the same constant $R$ for all $i$.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I wellcome your observations and revised my answer taking them into account.

Answer (score -1):

It follows quite simply from the one of the *definitions* of $e^x$ (saying "one of" the definitions a bit loosely to indicate that *any one* of them could be taken to be *the* definition) - $$e^x\equiv\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n .$$

The product of $n$ factors is a generalisation of the *raising to the power* of $n$ in the given (by me) limit definition, and that the argument of your exponential term is the *arithmetic mean* over all $x$ is the generalisation in *that* place corresponding to it.

One way we have of proving it in the *simple* case (let's call it) when it's just a single value of $x$, is to show that the binomial expansion *morphs into* the Taylor series for $e^x$ with $(n)_k$ (Pochhamner notation *desending*) becoming ever more nearly $n^k$ for a given value of $k$ (index *along* the series - the binomial *or* the Taylor) as $n$ increases. This will work also for the *compound* case (let's call it - infinite product of $n$ factors), if we can show that the sum of the products of the $x_i$ taken $k$ at a time becomes *more nearly like* $${\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\right)^k\over k!}\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\operatorname{¶}$$ for a given $k$ as $n$ increases in *the same manner as*, or a *similar manner to that in which*, $(n)_k$ becomes *more nearly like* $n^k$ ... or even in a *very different* manner, as long as it becomes more nearly like it: but that is not really to be expected. The difference consists in this last sum having $k$-fold products in it that are *not* fully hererogeneous - whereas in $$\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+{x_j \over n}\right)\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\operatorname{§}$$ *all* the $k$-fold products occuring in a sum of them are fully heterogeneous. The *total number* of $k$-fold products including the non-fully-heterogeneous ones in ¶ is $n^k$, so it becomes the more nearly completely *dominated* by the fully-heterogeneous ones in the same proportion as $(n)_k$ becomes the more like $n^k$. This is an *exact* analogy of the similutude - ever increasing with $n$ - of the $(n)_k$ in the binomial expansion to the $n^k$ in the Taylor series in the *simple* case - and differs in that rather than being a *pure number*, it is the number of *terms* in a *sum*.

I cannot prove at this present time that there is *absolutely no way* a pathological set of $x_j$ could be devised such that the fully heterogeneous terms in the sum fail to dominate the non-fully heterogeneous ones despite their ever-increasing preponderance - constituting a proportion $${(n)_k\over n^k}$$ of the total termage. But it certainly would be an *extremely* pathological set, the devising of which would demand *surpassing ingenuity*.

Ah! but I've just noticed that you said "assume they are bounded"! That prettymuch precludes anysuch "pathological set", I should think.

Comment: This is not enough.

Comment: I've put some more detail in for you.

Comment: That "surpassing ingenuity" remark ... it's probably not so. Certainly you could make it _trivially_ not so by having the x_j =  O(n^(1+ε)), with ε not negative. If you have x_j = o(n), then it might require some ingenuity ... if the set is bounded, I think it would require at least _considerable_ ingenuity to devise a 'pathological' one in the sense adduced.

Comment: I've put yet more in ... but under my post "Whether there's a Pathological Set that can Foil a Theorem about Exponentials" ... or something like that. You can get toitt easily through my profile anyway ... if you're still interested.